# How to safely downcast USTRUCTs

Tags: c++, reflection, polymorphism, unreal-engine4

Unreal Engine supports downcasting of [`UObject*`](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UClass/) via [`Cast<T>`](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/Templates/) and via a [custom implementation of `dynamic_cast<T*>`](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/Templates/UE4Casts_Private__DynamicCast/).

When downcasting [`USTRUCT`](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UScriptStruct) objects, both methods don't work:

1. The methods of `Cast<T>` do not support conversions to `UScriptStructs`.
2. UE4 compiles without RTTI (e.g. [`/GR-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gr-enable-run-time-type-information?view=vs-2019) is set for cl.exe) and UE4 uses the `dynamic_cast<T*>` of the implementation for pointers to `USTRUCT`s. Therefore the compiler throws [C4541](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4541) (see example below).

Is there a method in UE4.22 to *safely* downcast `USTRUCT`s using the reflection system of UE4 (so when `static_cast<T*>` etc is not an option)?

If not, then why UE4 doesn't support downcasting `USTRUCT`s by its Cast functions? E.g. shouldn't they be referenced or are the reasons Blueprint related?

---

Example for (2), use within an UE4 project:

```
#pragma once
#include "CoreMinimal.h"

USTRUCT()
struct MyStructBase
{
    virtual ~MyStructBase() = default;
};

USTRUCT()
struct MyStructDerived : public MyStructBase
{};

void TestFunc()
{
    auto lvalue = MyStructBase{};
    auto lvaluePtr = &lvalue;
    auto o = dynamic_cast<MyStructDerived*>(lvaluePtr); // cl.exe throws C4541
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a method in UE4.22 to safely downcast USTRUCTs using the reflection system of UE4 (so when static_cast<T*> etc is not an option)?

I know it's not an ideal solution and might not suit your case, but if you don't want to use a bare `static_cast`, you could provide a templated function that does the cast and add a `static_assert` with `TIsDerivedFrom` inside to get a compile time error were the cast to fail.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
T* CastStruct(U* base)
{
    static_assert(TIsDerivedFrom<T, U>::IsDerived, "Type T has to be derived from U.");
    return static_cast<T*>(base);
}
```

> why UE4 doesn't support downcasting `USTRUCTs` by its Cast functions?

That's because structures are supposed to be lightweight entities in Unreal Engine and thus reflection - which is required for `Cast` to work - is <s>not provided</s> provided in a minimal form for them.

Be careful when using pointers to `USTRUCTs` as they're not only unsupported by reflection, but also garbage collector, serializers, UI etc. You have to know what you're doing when dealing with them.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1556479-casting-ustruct-to-derrived-struct) in the Unreal forums, there is no working dynamic cast for `UStruct` in Unreal. I'm not sure why, but it seems that pointers to objects of type `UStruct` are not support by Unreal's reflection system, according to this [post](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/108339-can-use-use-inheritence-with-ustructs).

Your options here include a C-style cast and like you mentioned, a static cast. However, either option isn't that safe, with the exception that static casts are usually safe when you know the object being passed to the cast is of the type specified in the cast.

C-style cast:

```
auto o = (MyStructDerived*) lvaluePtr;
```

Static cast:

```
auto o = static_cast<MyStructDerived*>(lvaluePtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the safety of a structure cast by checking if the type of the structure is a child of the type you're casting to, and the type you're casting to is a child of the structure type. If both conditions are true they're the same type.